# Combining Forecasts: Best Information to Solicit from Forecasters?

Tags: forecasting, forecast-combination

Suppose

- Statistician $m=1$ produces a set of $h$-step-ahead point forecasts $\hat{x}_{t+h|t, 1}$ of $x_{t+h}$ where $x_{t+h} \in [0,1]$.
- Also, this point forecast could come with:

  - a predictive density $f_{{x}_{t+h|t,1}}(x|x_t,...,x_1)$
  - a predictive error $\hat{\sigma}_{t+h|t, 1}$
  - a $(1-\alpha)\%$ predictive interval $(c_{t+h|t,1,\alpha,lb},c_{t+h|t,1,\alpha,ub})$
  - or no measure of certainty in forecast at all
- After seeing this first forecast $\hat{x}_{t+h|t, 1}$, there are $M$ statistically unsophisticated forecasters with domain knowledge who could each produce their own point forecasts $\hat{x}_{t+h|t, m}$, $m=2,...,M+1$.
- After seeing all $\hat{x}_{t+h|t, m}$, $m=1,...,M+1$, a combined forecast is constructed $\bar{x}_{t+h|t, m} = \sum_{m=1}^{M+1} w_{t+h|t,m}\hat{x}_{t+h|t, m}$ where $w_{t+h|t,m} \geq 0$ and $\sum_{m=1}^{M+1}w_{t+h|t,m}=1 $

**Q: What additional piece of info would you solicit from the forecasters $m=2,...,M+1$ to help you construct the optimal forecast combination weights $w_{t+h|t,m}$? How would you use that info to construct the weights?**

Suppose additionally,

- A backtested measure of model forecast accuracy (e.g., MAPE) could exist for $m=1$ but does not exists for $m=2,...,M+1$
- These forecasters are statistically unsophisticated, so asking for their $\hat{\sigma}_{t+h|t, m}$ might not be as meaningful as asking for their predictive interval
- These forecasters don't have a lot of time and, so, are unlikely to produce predictive densities for each of their forecasts
- Forecaster $m$ usually only produces a forecast in periods $t$ where they believe the forecast $m=1$ is flawed. So $\hat{x}_{t+h|t, m}$ won't exist for all $t$

I think the leading candidates for additional info are:

- predictive interval for the $m>1$ forecast (which, theoretically, would be constructed independently from the $\hat{x}_{t+h|t,1}$)
- probability that the $m>1$ forecast is closer to the actual than the $m=1$ forecast (i.e., $\Pr\{|\hat{x}_{t+h|t, m}-x_{t+h}| < |\hat{x}_{t+h|t, 1}-x_{t+h}|\}$ where $m>1$)
- probability that the the the actual is greater than the $m=1$ forecast (i.e., $\Pr\{x_{t+h} > \hat{x}_{t+h|t, 1}\})$

But I'm not really sure how one would use this info to construct optimal weights (even less so with the second and third pieces of info.) The top answer to [Assigning Weights to an Averaged Forecast](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163074/assigning-weights-to-an-averaged-forecast) has a lot of great suggestions on how to combine forecasts. But they all assume some track record of error or a full predictive distribution, which doesn't exist here. Averaging forecasts and predictive bounds would be so simple. But it really isn't sufficient here. There needs to be a way to down-weight uncertain predictions and, with time, forecasters who've developed a track-record of inaccuracy.

Comment: The prior elicitation literature should be really helpful here including suggestions on how to elicit distributions/uncertainty.

Comment: @Björn: are you thinking of papers like [Statistical Methods for Eliciting Probability Distributions](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/016214505000000105#.Vd-kp_lVhBc)?

Comment: Yes, that looks like it should be useful*. 

* I only read the abstract, from which this one looks like it could be quite helpful. Also, one of the co-authors (Tony O'Hagan) is well-known as an expert on this topic.