# Optimal prediction pools in practice

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models, markov-chain-montecarlo

In their paper [Optimal Prediction Pools](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwj25-eQ7IPLAhVG_g4KHTPCAa0QFggsMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.riksbank.se%2FUpload%2FDokument_riksbank%2FKat_foa%2F2008%2FSep_8_Geweke.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH_Um_doywUpw6Dgy8dlyujfds0Fg&sig2=eMMxC5bYS3ssdF6X6POhgQ&cad=rja), John Geweke and Gianni Amisano propose a rather intuitive approach to form linear opinion pools to combine different forecasts. As pointed out in [this excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163074/assigning-weights-to-an-averaged-forecast/163142#163142) from @Zachary Blumenfeld their method does not require that the true predictive Model is included, in my opinion a rather important property (if not, essential).

However, I do struggle a bit when it comes to implementing the Theory into Practice:

To make it simple, let's assume I have two model assumptions $A_1$ and $A_2$ defining Bayesian models, giving me the possibility to sample at time point $t$ from the posterior distribution $p(\Theta_i|Y_{t-1},A_i)$ for the set of parameters $\Theta$ of Model $A_i$ via MCMC where $Y_{t-1}=\{y_1,\ldots,y_{t-1}\}$. Therefore, I obtain two sequences $\{\Theta_1 ^{(m)}\}$ and $\{\Theta_2 ^{(m)}\}$.

The optimal prediction pool corresponds to choosing the linear combination 
$$\omega_T ^0 =\arg\max_{\omega\in[0,1]}\sum\limits_{t=1}^{T}log[wp(y_t^o|Y_{t-1},\Theta_1,A_1)+(1-\omega)p(y_t^o|Y_{t-1},\Theta_2,A_2)]$$
where $y_t ^0$ is the observed value at time $t$. 
My question is how to compute the value of the one-step-ahead predictive likelihood $$p(y_t^o|Y_{t-1},A_i):=\int_{\Theta_i}p(y_t ^0|Y_{t-1},\Theta_i,A_i)p(\Theta_i|Y_{t-1},A_i)d\Theta_i$$ based on my MCMC samples. Is it correct to use Monte-Carlo Integration here by computing $p(y_t ^0|Y_{t-1},\Theta_i ^{(m)},A_i)$ for each of the $m$ draws and then just take the average to approximate the integral via
$$\frac{1}{M}\sum\limits_{m=1}^Mp(y_t ^0|Y_{t-1},\Theta_i ^{(m)},A_i)$$ as pointed out on page 7 of [this paper](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiAlcDX8YPLAhVLFSwKHf1hBvMQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ecb.europa.eu%2Fpub%2Fpdf%2Fscpwps%2Fecbwp969.pdf%3F0abe9078b466b4defd08dbbf9ac24f39&usg=AFQjCNF3xUREtesDMexS8eNiO85HZTwn-w&sig2=1M6OZbAhW8QCHFwEu1jXQw)?