# Usage of AIC for comparing models

Tags: aic, exponential-smoothing

Can AIC be used to compare a model with exponential smoothing with linear regressions?

Comment: This exact question has been answered by Rob J. Hyndman [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/59135/can-you-compare-aic-values-as-long-as-the-models-are-based-on-the-same-dataset?rq=1). However, it is only the *answer* in that thread that matches this question while the *question* there is different; so this is not a duplicate, IMHO. See also [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/can-aic-compare-across-different-types-of-model?rq=1) thread.

Comment: It seems to me that the important aspect of being a duplicate is that the question has already been answered , not that the threads are identical. I'm voting to close.

Comment: The question is certainly phrased differently but I'm not sure its content differs substantially, at least the crux of the question seems the same.